Changes made to Panel table not reflecting in dataframe Vertex AI environment
I'm facing an issue with Panel library while trying to modify values directly from a table within a Vertex AI environment. Here's the problem:
I'm using the Panel library to create a table widget (pn.widgets.Tabulator) in Python. The table is populated with data from a Pandas DataFrame. I've implemented functionality to modify the values directly from the table itself. This setup works fine when I run the code locally or in a Colab environment. However, when I try the same code in Vertex AI, the changes made to the table are not reflected.
Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import panel as pn

np.random.seed(7)
pn.extension('tabulator')
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'int': [1, 2, 3],
    'float': [3.14, 6.28, 9.42],
    'str': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'bool': [True, False, True],
    'date': [dt.date(2019, 1, 1), dt.date(2020, 1, 1), dt.date(2020, 1, 10)],
    'datetime': [dt.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 10), dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 12), dt.datetime(2020, 1, 10, 13)]
}, index=[1, 2, 3])

df_widget = pn.widgets.Tabulator(df, buttons={'Print': "<i class='fa fa-print'></i>"})
df_widget

I have verified that I'm using the same versions of libraries in all environments, and there are no errors or exceptions thrown when running the code in Vertex AI.
Is there any specific configuration or workaround needed to ensure that changes made to the Panel table are reflected in Vertex AI environment? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
I want to see changes in dataframe which i am doing in panel table
